# Get Position subjects in exams by Students using Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.3

I have a table called results with the following columns ID, Reg Number,Name, Subjects,Programmes,Year,Term,score. i want get positions of every subject by student where Programmes = Art and year = 2017 and Term = 1.

```
        $getResults = DB::table('results')
        ->leftjoin(DB::raw('((SELECT regNumber, score, programmes,term,year, subject_position from 
        (SELECT regNumber, score, programmes,term,year, subject_position,
            CASE WHEN @prevRank = score THEN @curRank WHEN @prevRank := score THEN @curRank := @curRank + 1 END AS subject_position FROM results p, 
            (SELECT @curRank :=0, @prevRank := NULL) r2  

                          where programmes ="'.$getProgramme.'" and  `year` = "'.$getLevel.'" and term = "'.$getTerm.'"
                          and year = "'.$getYear.'" ORDER BY score Desc) as t3 )'), function($joinn)
        {
            $joinn->on('regNumber', '=', 'results.regNumber')                    

        })      

        ->where('programmes',$getProgramme)
        ->where('year',$getYear)
        ->where('term',$getTerm)
        ->where('level',$getLevel)
        ->get();
```

Below is the what i want to achieve. To get the shaded subjectpositions:

[image: Below is the what i want to achieve. To get the shaded subjectpositions.]

Comment: Have you considered using Eloquent? Since you're using Laravel, you could use Eloquent models to represent an entity in your database, e.g. Student or Subject.
Take a look at the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent

Comment: I am a bit new in laravel and i need an understand on how to achieve it.

Comment: Reading those docs should suffice. Also Laracasts has some videos that teach you to do just that. Using Eloquent would MASSIVELY simplify your queries, rather than having to write all that SQL by hand. Once I'm on a computer I can post a possible answer to this as if you were using Eloquent.

Comment: i really appreciate your time, please try and post possible answers once you sit behind a computer. i really need this help. Thank you

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: Assuming you created an Eloquent model "Result" for your table results:

Result::where('Programmes', 'Art')
    ->where('year', '2017')
    ->where('Term', '1')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('Subject Postion');

Notice how I kept the column names you have. I would recommend however that you change them all to lowercase.

If you do get Eloquent roling, let me know and I'll write a proper response

Comment: $getScores = ViewResults::where('programmes', $getProgramme)
             ->where('ternYear',$getYear)
             ->where('termDesc',$getTerm)
             ->where('level',$getLevel)
             ->get()->pluck('Subject Postion');

                dd($getScores);

I get eloquent rolling with collection with 71 array in the collection.

Comment: So is your query returning the proper results? I'll post a full answer once I'm home today 

Comment: Yes, the right number of records in the array but is empty.  please, will be waiting. Thanks

Comment: Check the answer below. We'll keep discussing in its thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you used Eloquent, you would represent your entity like so:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Result extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'Reg Number',
        'Name',
        'Subjects',
        'Programmes',
        'Year',
        'Term',
        'score',
        'Subject Postion',
    ];
}
```

**Notice I am using the same column names as in the image you posted.**
Since they are inconsistent with the query columns, I chose the image as it has more information on your table schema.

So for your query:

> i want get positions of every subject by student where Programmes =
>   Art and year = 2017 and Term = 1.

You could do this like

```
Result::where('Programmes', 'Art')
    ->where('year', 2017)
    ->where('Term', 1)
    ->get()
    ->pluck('Subject Postion');
```

**Again, please note I am using the same column names and values as in your example.**

I would probably standardize the column names, as I feel it might be a source of confusion and probably doesn't help your thinking. Lowercase snake_case would be my way to go. e.g.:

```
registration_number, name, subject, programme, year, term, score, subject_position
```

Definitely something to keep in mind moving forward!

Comment: It seems you didn’t get my question. The subject position column is not a column on the table. It is suppose to be calcated with the query using the score. So the eloquent is to get the subject position and add to the collection.

Comment: I see. What's the formula?

Comment: From the image, the student with the highest score in the subject get first position in 5he subject with specific term, year and programme